# C : printf() not thread safe with flockfile()

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, printf, posix

I need to print some messages on screen, and my program is multiprocess and multithread. I used `flockfile()`, `flock()` and mutex, but some messages are overlapped. I did also a basic test program, and the result is the same. Why i cannot synchronize the output?

```
void my_printf() {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<20000; ++i) {
        flockfile(stdout);
        printf("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        funlockfile(stdout);
    }
}


int main()
{
    fork();
    fork();
    fork();
    my_printf();
    exit(0);
}
```

EDIT

@Joachim Pileborg
I have tried to use `sem_t` semaphores, but i had the same result...strings are overlapped.

```
struct my_struct {
    sem_t *t;
};

struct my_struct *create_shared_memory(void)
{
    struct my_struct *str;
    key_t key;
    int fd;

    key = ftok("/", '5');
    fd = shmget(key, sizeof(struct my_struct), IPC_CREAT|0666);
    str = shmat(fd, NULL, 0);
    str->t = sem_open("/my_sem", O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0644, 1);

    return str;
}

void my_printf(struct my_struct *str){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<20000; ++i) {
        sem_wait(str->t);
        printf("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\n");
        sem_post(str->t);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}


int main()
{
    struct my_struct *my = create_shared_memory();
    fork();
    fork();
    my_printf(my);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You should `fflush` before you `sem_post`.

Comment: @Schwartz i have tried it too, but same result

Comment: You seem to have tried to split the difference between named and unnamed semaphores.

Comment: I'm working on xCode, and 'sem_init()' for unnamed semaphore is deprecated. I just tried the named ones, but i have the same result. I know that is unnecessary create a shared memory for named sem, but with or without it, the result is the same. I just want to know why

Answer (score 3):

The [`flockfile`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/flockfile.3.html) function is for locking for other *threads*, not processes. If you want inter-process locking look at e.g. [POSIX semaphores](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html), especially the named ones.

Comment: So, i have to use `pthread_mutex_t`??

EDIT:
Sorry, i have read now the link!!
Is there another way to lock stdout for processes and threads?

Comment: @Simon If you lock acces for processes, that will lock it for threads as well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This is not true. For example, `flock` locks will do terrible things if you try to use them to lock between threads.